# numpy.unique doesn't give the expected output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array. When I print it in this way;

```
print len(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3]).astype(int))
```

I get 6278. But when I print the minimum and maximum int values of the same array with numpy.amax and numpy.amin;

```
print numpy.amax(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3]).astype(int))
print numpy.amin(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3]).astype(int))
```

I get 286, and 0. Is it possible to have 6278 unique values between 0, and 286? Of course, not!

What should I do to get the number of unique values?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `astype(int)` before calling unique, not after.

This is **not** the same (unique applied to the original data type):

```
print numpy.amax(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3]).astype(int))
print numpy.amin(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3]).astype(int))
```

as this (unique applied to ints):

```
print numpy.amax(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3].astype(int)))
print numpy.amin(numpy.unique(all_data[:, 3].astype(int)))
```

Note: Pay attention to how in the latter `as type` is applied **before**: `all_data[:, 3].astype(int)` calling unique